# Change Authorization and Authentication Order Net.Core 3.1

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, identityserver4, action-filter, authorize

We have an Identity Server 4 to authorize users and custom authorization in API project.

I want to set both of these authorizations together, but first check Identity Server 4 and then my custom authorization.

The problem is, this order does not work and my custom authorization executes first. How can I change this order?

Startup.cs

```
        services.AddAuthorization(authorizationOptions =>
        {
            authorizationOptions.AddPolicy(
               name: "UserAccess",
               configurePolicy: policyBuilder =>
               {
                   policyBuilder.RequireAuthenticatedUser();
                   policyBuilder.AddRequirements(new UserAccessRequirement());
               });
        }).AddAuthentication(defaultScheme: IdentityServerAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddIdentityServerAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.Authority = "https://*******.land/";
            options.ApiName = "****.Api";
            options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
        });
```

My custom authorization:

```
public class UserAccessHandler : AuthorizationHandler<UserAccessRequirement>
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _accessor;

    public UserAccessHandler(IHttpContextAccessor accessor)
    {
        _accessor = accessor ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(accessor));
    }

    protected override async Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, UserAccessRequirement requirement)
    {
        var httpContext = _accessor.HttpContext;
        /// Some Code
    }
}
```

In API controllers:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
[Authorize]
public class TestController : ControllerBase
{
        [Authorize(policy: "UserAccess")]
        [HttpGet("[action]")]
        public IActionResult Get()
        {
            return Ok("Access");
        }
}
```

---

Updated:

```
    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllers();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use the AddIdentityServerAuthentication method for new development as it seems to be deprecated and not supported anymore

see https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.AccessTokenValidation

In your API that receives access tokens from your client you should use:

```
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddJwtBearer(opt =>
    {
        opt.Audience = "payment";  //api name
        opt.Authority = "https://identityservice.local:6001";  //URL to your identityserver
    });
```

AddIdentityServerAuthentication is not meant to be used in the API.

---

Updated:

```
    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllers();
    });
```

Comment: this change the execution order?

Comment: What does your configure method look like in Startup.cs? UseAuthentication should always be before UseAuthorization.  What do you mean with execution order?

Comment: yes, i use this

See my Updated code

Comment: When you write,  "this order does not work and my custom authorization executes first. How can I change this order?", ?

Can you be more clear about what is executed after the authorization?

Comment: Yes, I want first check user Token that get from Identity server 4, and then check the policy that exist in custom middleware , but this not happened. after i call this API, first custom middleware execute without checking Token and throw Exception because there i no User! that's wired!

Comment: I would try with using AddJwtBearer instead to get the user from he access token... can you post a sample access token?

Comment: Access token that create in identity server?

Comment: The access token that the client that sent the access token got from IdentityServer. Or how did you get the access token?

Comment: i Get the access token from my client (Flutter), and test it with PostMan, everything works fine, except this order!

i can write my middleware with TypeFilterAttribute (change the AuthorizationHandler to TypeFilterAttribute) and problem will solve, but it's not correct

Comment: What status code do you get back from the API? How to you pass the access token to the API? authorization: bearer ey.....? please post a sample token and request to your question

Comment: Ok i will post it